# Error in a "for" loop, I think memory problems

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an algorithm that loops through the loop 'for' ten times, the ultimate goal is to print out a 50x50 matrix with the sum of the values ​​greater than or equal to 49, 0, and 1 represented as '*', but for some strange reason the loop only does 3 iterations instead of 10. ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printsimulaciodeu(int matlefa[50][50]) {
int ii, jj;
for (ii = 0; ii < 50; ii++) {
    for (jj = 0; jj < 50; jj++) {
        if(matlefa[ii][jj] == 0) {
            printf(" 0 ");
        }
        else if (matlefa[ii][jj] >= 49) {
            printf(" %d ", matlefa[ii][jj]-48);
        }
        else {
            printf(" * ");
            }
    }
    printf("\n");    
}
}
int main(){
    int tabla[50][50]={ 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    };

    int its;
    int i, j;
    int disparos_pos[10] = {1, 5, 14, 22, 37, 48, 43, 40, 28, 19};
    char disparos_dir[10]= {'i','i','d','i','d','d','i','d','d','i'};
    int mataux[50][50];
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            mataux[i][j] = tabla[i][j];
        }
    }
    int matsuma[50][50];
    for (its = 0; its < 10; its++) {
        int pos = disparos_pos[its];
        int dir = disparos_dir[its];
        i = 0;
        j = pos;
        int cont = 49;
        while (i < 49) {
            if (mataux[i+1][j] == 0) {
                mataux[i+1][j] = cont;
                ++i;
            }
            else {
                if (dir == 'i') {
                    if (mataux[i+1][j] != 0) {
                        if (mataux[i][j-1] == 0) {
                            mataux[i][j-1] = cont;
                            --j;
                        }
                        else {
                            dir = 'd';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (dir == 'd') {
                    if (mataux[i+1][j] != 0) {
                        if (mataux[i][j+1] == 0) {
                            mataux[i][j+1] = cont;
                            ++j;
                        }
                        else {
                            dir = 'i';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (its == 0) {
            int m, n;
            for (m = 0; m < 50; m++) {
                for (n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
                    matsuma[m][n] = mataux[m][n];
                }
            }
        }
        if (its > 0) {
            int p, q;
            for (p = 0; p < 50; p++) {
                for (q = 0; q < 50; q++) {                
                    if (mataux[p][q] == 49) {
                        if (matsuma[p][q] >= 49) {
                            matsuma[p][q] = matsuma[p][q]+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printsimulaciodeu(matsuma);
}
```

I thought that one possibility is that the memory for the process is complete and therefore not iterate correctly, is that possible?

please help, I need it to work well for college work.

Comment: Debug or print out progress. Do something like adding `printf("Now doing loop %d\n", its);` at the beginning of the loop. Or `watch` `its` in a debugger.

Comment: 1. Which loop are you talking about? 2. I'd recommend to avoid allocating such data structures as your 50x50 matrices (50x50x4 are roughly 10kB of data per matrix instance) on the stack in order to not overload the stack with data. 3. Maybe you want to restructure some code so it's more readable and maintanable. For example I'd do the various data processing in distinct functions just to keep the overview better.

Comment: 1. `printsimulaciodeu()` looks fine, I can't figure out what most of the rest of the code is doing. 2. I agree with all of junix's comments. 3. Use `#define MATSIZE 50` instead of hard-coding 50 all over the place.

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], you're not compiling it as both, so pick one

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of debugging, I figured out the actual problem: Your while loop will run for INFINITE time in 3rd iteration of for loop.

**Explaination**

The while loop runs OK until i=33
at i=33 (j = 21, dir = 'i'), the none of the assignment statements (mataux[blah][blah] = blah balh) are executed, as conditons turn out to be false. Ultimate result is that value of 'dir' is toggled between 'i' and 'd', and the loop will run for forever!!

**Details**

mataux[i+1][j] = mataux[34][21] = 1 != 0 ---> first IF skipped

mataux[i][j-1] = mataux[33][20] = 49 != 0 ---> third IF in first ELSE of WHILE skipped

ELSE --> dir = 'd' (100)

mataux[i][j+1] = mataux[33][22] = 1 != 0 ---> third IF in last IF block skipped

ELSE --> dir = "i" (105)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome. Also please do refactor your code. It helps others to figure out quickly what are you trying to achieve in your code.